# Interrupting boost thread 

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I would like to be able to interrupt a thread as follows.

```
void mainThread(char* cmd)
{   
    if (!strcmp(cmd, "start"))
        boost::thread thrd(sender); //start thread

    if (!strcmp(cmd, "stop"))
        thrd.interrupt();       // doesn't work, because thrd is undefined here

}
```

**thrd.interrupt()** is not possible because **thrd** object is undefined when I try to interrupt it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [move assignment operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.move_assignment):

```
void mainThread(char* cmd)
{   
    boost::thread thrd;

    if (!strcmp(cmd, "start"))
        thrd = boost::thread(sender); //start thread

    if (!strcmp(cmd, "stop"))
        thrd.interrupt();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boost thread is movable, so you can do something like:

```
boost::thread myThread;
if ( isStart ) {
    myThread = boost::thread(sender);
else if ( isStop ) {
    myThread.interrupt();
}
```

If you want to pass it around (e.g. as an argument to the function),
you'll probably want to use a pointer or a reference:

```
void
mainThread( std::string const& command, boost::thread& aThread )
{
    if ( command == "start" ) {
        aThread = boost::thread( sender );
    } else if ( command == "stop" ) {
        aThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

(This probably needs more.  For example, as written, if you execute
`mainThread( "start" )` twice in a row, you'll detach the first thread,
and never be able to refer to it again.)

Another alternative would be to use boost::shared_ptr.

Comment: In the `else if` of the first code shouldn't be `isStop` or something similar instead or `isStart`?.

Comment: @AdriC.S. Yes.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a question about boost::thread, it's about scope:

this:

```
if(Condition)
    MyType foo;
... // foo is out of scope
foo.method(); // won't work, no foo in scope
```

is the same as this:

```
if(Condition) 
{
    MyType foo;
} // after this brace, foo no longer exists, so...
foo.method(); // won't work, no foo in scope
```

Notice that the answers above all do something like:

```
MyType foo:
if (Condition)
    foo.method(); // works because now there is a foo in scope
else
{
    foo.otherMethod(); // foo in scope here, too.
}
```