# boost::thread interrupt asynchronously

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I would like to use threads in a switch.  Is this possible or is there another way to interrupt the thread elsewhere in the program?

```
switch (event_element)    // dispatch event handler
{
    case 1: // main task thread
    {
        boost::thread thr_check_db_task (check_db_task);
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        std::cerr << "DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR" << std::endl;
        thr_check_db_task.interrupt ();        // **COMPILE ERROR**
        mysql_connection_error ();
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are accessing an out-of-scope local variable `thr-check-db_task`. That's why you got an error. One way is to keep it as a member variable of the class.

Comment: You didn't post the compiler error you're getting, so I'll guess that its something along the lines of  "`thr_check_db_task` not declared in this scope"? If it is, then it makes sense.. `the_check_db_task` is clearly not in the scope of case 2.

Comment: Yes, you are both right.  How can I start a thread and interrupt it asynchronously?

Comment: @xinthose See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705733/interrupting-boost-thread).

```
boost::thread thr_check_db_task;

switch (event_element)    // dispatch event handler
{
    case 1: // main task thread
    {
        thr_check_db_task = boost::thread (check_db_task);
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        std::cerr << "DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR" << std::endl;
        thr_check_db_task.interrupt ();
        mysql_connection_error ();
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

I knew the answer was simpler than creating a complex class.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to put this thread object as a member variable of the according class so that it can be shared among function calls of this class.

E.g.,

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

class tMyApp
{
   struct callable
   {
      void operator()()
      {
         // Do something and wait to be interrupted
         while (true)
         {
            /* .. */
         }
      }
   };

public:
   tMyApp(): m_thread(m_threadProc)
   {
      /* do something.. */

      m_thread.interrupt();
   }

private:
   callable m_threadProc;
   // The thread object
   boost::thread m_thread;
};
```

Comment: thank you; how would I use this from int main exactly?  My switch is in int main.

Comment: You can use either a pointer to a heap-allocated thread object, or use the swap/move approach. You make a NULL pointer or a default-constructed object prior to the `switch`.